# TabHost containing a tabwidget that does not start a activity

Tags: android, android-activity, tabs

I have 4 tabwidgets and when i click the first three of them they must start their respective activities and when I click the fourth tab the layout should be the previous activities on the background  and a quickaction type dialog box just below the tab must pop up. Is this possible. Someone please give suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Hope that will help!
In your class TabhostActivity (extends TabActivity), you've to add:

```
Resources res = getResources();
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;
    Intent intent;

    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, your_first_tab.class);

    // Initialize a TabSpec for the first tab
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("").setIndicator("",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_name_of_the_first_tab)).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

// Initialize a TabSpec for the second tab
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, your_second_tab.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("").setIndicator("",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_name_of_the_second_tab)).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

Same work for the others.

---

ic_tab_name_of_the_first_tab is a xml file like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- When selected, use grey -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/first_icon_grey"
      android:state_selected="true" />
<!-- When not selected, use white-->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/first_icon_white" />
```